# WCAG/ADA Compliant Notice

Tags: wcag

A client would like to notify its users that their website is ADA compliant. Let's say the site meets all the criteria to be compliant, and all the copy is written by their legal/copy teams, where would a notification best be applicable on the site?

At first I was thinking a brief snippet in the footer, but that text would generally be small. My next guess would be somewhere in the Privacy Policy, but I'm not sure this topic relates to the "privacy policy."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of your client notifying the user that they're ADA compliant?

Is it because a requirement for being compliant states that they need to say that they are? If that's the case, check the ADA requirements on how to display this.

Is it because they want to have it on there just because they are compliant? If that's the case, then the footer is fine for that kind of stuff (similar to the website is copyrighted information - stuff that needs to be said, but isn't primary).

Is it because they want to make the whole world know that they are ADA compliant? (bragging, brownie points, whatever you want to call it). If that's the case, then you have several options.

Make it really stand out (something that is "different" than most websites and calls attention):

- A top-left or top-right corner tag
- A side tag
- A sepearte top bar that can be closed with an "X" (ie. like the ones that say "this site stores cookies")
- A pop-up

Make it more subtle (but keep it in a location that still normally gets looked at):

- Underneath the company logo
- In/under the navigation bar/menu

Comment: I honestly think this is more of a CYA thing, but you gave me some really good questions to ask if/when this comes up in meetings about it.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Davbog's ideas to clarify the **why** first, then decide where to put such a statement based on the "why".

There's an excellent article on "[Developing an Accessibility Statement](https://www.w3.org/WAI/planning/statements/)" from the W3C's WAI (Web Accessibility Initiative) group.  It talks about why you should have an accessibility statement, what to include in it, where to put it, and some generic examples.

For a real world example, see [Capital One's accessibility statement page](https://www.capitalone.com/about/accessibility-commitment/).  I like that they have multiple contact methods - chat, phone call, etc.

Comment: Really appreciate the links for the example because I had no idea where to look. I like that Capital One has this in their "About" section.

Comment: Too bad two answers can’t be marked accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that ongoing web site ADA compliance is a moving target, and web site that was fully in compliance one day might not be so once content changes are made via CMS.  Putting that little snippet about being fully in compliance can open a whole can of worms from legal perspective once something, some time from now, turns out to be not in compliance.